# Implementation of abstract trait method in PHP

Tags: php, traits

I have a class that looks like [this](https://3v4l.org/HKC2p). I will also paste it below for reference:

```
<?php

trait T1
{
    abstract protected function _doStuff();
}

trait T2
{
    protected function _doStuff()
    {
        echo "Doing stuff in trait\n";
    }
}

class C
{
    use T1 {
        _doStuff as _traitDoStuff;
    }

    use T2 {
        _doStuff as _traitDoStuff;
    }

    protected function _doStuff()
    {
        echo "Doing stuff in class\n";

        $this->_traitDoStuff();
    }
}
```

Here's what's happening here:

1. `T1::_doStuff()` is used, and aliased as `_traitDoStuff()`. As per PHP docs, this does not rename the method, but only adds an alias. So at this point, both `_doStuff()` and `_traitDoStuff()` exist as abstract protected methods.
2. `T2::_doStuff()` is used, and aliased as `_traitDoStuff()`. As per PHP docs, due to precedence, both are overridden by methods of `T2`. So at this point, `T1::_doStuff()` no longer exists. Even if it would, it would be implemented by `T2::_doStuff()`.
3. `C` implements `_doStuff()`, which calls `_traitDoStuff()`. At this point, regardless of which implementation of `_doStuff()` is used, it is obvious that this method is implemented, so the contract defined by `T1::_doStuff()` is satisfied, or doesn't exist.

And yet, when I run this, it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Class C contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (C::_doStuff)

As can be seen from 3v4l, this manifests everywhere from PHP 5.4 to 7.2, which kinda hints that this is not an early trait bug. Can somebody please explain this to me?

### Update

Apparently, I just forgot to specify the method that I am aliasing, i.e. `T1::_doStuff as _traitDoStuff`.

Comment: Shouldn't T1 be implemented as an interface, not a trait?

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to mean, @bassxzero.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: I know what interfaces are. I don't know what your sentence means. I have a trait. I don't understand what it means for a trait to be implemented as an interface.

Comment: Shouldn't class C implement the T1 interface. Put your abstract function `do_stuff` inside an interface called `T1`, then make class C implement the T1 interface.

Comment: Why would you have 2 traits and have there methods equate to the same name, what is the point of this?  As you say yourself, as T2 overrides T1 you don't define a function to satisfy the abstract method in T1.

Comment: There is no `T1` interface. There's `T1` trait. And you cannot put an abstract method inside an interface, because they're all abstract. And you cannot have a protected method in an interface, because that would defeat the point of an interface. And also, it doesn't appear that you know what you're talking about.

Comment: @NigelRen, "why" is besides the point. This is just a distilled version of an actual problem. There are reasons for why it is that way.

Comment: Yeah! He's got reasons! *Big* reasons! *Big* ***secret*** reasons! Code so amazing that it needs an entirely new paradigm in which to define interfaces as abstract traits. Your puny mind would *explode* if you saw the code. It's the best code. Bigly good code.

Comment: lol wat. I am not defining interfaces as abstract traits (not sure what that means anyway). In my case, I have traits. Many traits. The case is complicated. And it's not "instead"; it's a completely different thing used for a different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that maybe ?

```
<?php

trait T1
{
    abstract protected function _doStuff();
}

trait T2
{
    protected function _doStuff()
    {
        echo "Doing stuff in trait\n";
    }
}

class C
{
    use T1 {
        T1::_doStuff as _traitDoStuff;
    }

    use T2 {
        T2::_doStuff as _traitDoStuff;
    }

    protected function _doStuff()
    {
        echo "Doing stuff in class\n";

        $this->_traitDoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: I add `T1::` and `T2::`. I try this code on http://phptester.net/ and I didn't get any error. Hope that help you

Comment: But I'm not sure why your first code not work. I was thinking both syntax was correct so if someone know why, please make a post to explain :)

Comment: Yea. I would also like to know, what does `_doStuff as _traitDoStuff` actually do.

Comment: I will explain... First code was not worked because in `T1` trait you have declared `function _doStuff()` as `abstract` and that abstract method you are using in `class C` without implemented. That is the reason behind it.

Comment: If you read *my* explanation in the question, you will see that this is not the case. The method `_doStuff()` is both overridden and implemented in class `C`.

Comment: Also, this is not the explanation I asked for. I understand very well how inheritance and abstract methods work. I also understand very well how trait composition works. I asked to explain what `_doStuff as _traitDoStuff` does, as opposed to `T1::_doStuff as _traitDoStuff`.

Comment: @Kozame I've taken a stab at an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378597/2908724).

Answer (score 3):

The lack of class-scope resolution operators (`T1::` and `T2::`) were masking a deeper issue. Consider these [simpler cases](https://3v4l.org/Zf9SR):

```
trait A {                                                                        
    abstract public function foo();                                              
}                                                                                

class B {                                                                        
    use A; // works                                                              
    public function foo() {}                                                     
}                                                                                

class C {                                                                        
    use A { A::foo as traitFoo; } // works, provided this:                       
    public function traitFoo() {} // <-- is present                              
    public function foo() {}                                                     
}                                                                                

class D {                                                                        
    use A { A::foo as traitFoo; } // does not work by itself                     
    public function foo() {}                                                     
}
```

What actually happens: aliasing an abstract method introduces *another* abstract method in your class. The PHP.net engine error message is hugely misleading:

> Fatal error: Class D contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (D::foo)

But the HHVM engine is far more informative:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class D contains abstract method (traitFoo) and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

The [Horizontal Reuse (aka Trait) RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse) does not explicitly discuss this case, so this is arguably a bug. Feel free to report it at [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net).

---

So why did adding the class resolution operator fix it?

When you added the class-scope resolution operators, which contained:

```
use T2 { T2::_doStuff as _traitDoStuff; }
```

you were satisfying the "phantom" `abstract protected function _traitDoStuff` introduced by:

```
use T1 { T1::_doStuff as _traitDoStuff; }
```

If you had removed the aliasing, like `use T2;` or `use T2 { T2::_doStuff as _anotherMethod; }` you would see the same crash.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation !!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!